# how to put single quote in sql query using implode

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to make a dynamic query so select some value from table but because of columns value without single quote is fails.

```
if(isset($_POST['Filter'])) {
    $filter = array('MC_SERIAL' => $_POST['mc-serial'],
              'ID'  => $_POST['id'],
              'START_DATE' => $_POST['start-date'],
              'END_DATE' => $_POST['end-date'],
               );
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $query_array = array();
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != ''){ 
            $query_array[] = $key.' = '.$value;
        }
    }
    if ($type == 'AMC'){
        $tableName = 'AMC';
    }
    if ($type == '4C'){
        $tableName = '4C';
    }
    if ($type == 'RENTAL'){
        $tableName = 'RENTAL';
    }
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE '.implode('AND', $query_array);
    echo $query;    
}
```

my above code is giving me

```
SELECT * FROM AMC WHERE MC_SERIAL = test001 AND ID = 001 AND START_DATE = 01-01-2017
```

but I want something like this

```
SELECT * FROM AMC WHERE MC_SERIAL = 'test001' AND ID = '001' AND START_DATE = '01-01-2017'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not use `$_POST` values without any escaping. This code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. If you use `MySQLi` at least [escape](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) values (as a benefit, you will not need to worry about `'` and `"` in a filter)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Filter'])) {
    $filter = array(
        'MC_SERIAL' => $_POST['mc-serial'],
        'ID' => $_POST['id'],
        'START_DATE' => $_POST['start-date'],
        'END_DATE' => $_POST['end-date'],
    );
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $query_array = array();
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != '') {
            $query_array[] = $key . ' = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($value) . '"';
        }
    }
    if ($type == 'AMC') {
        $tableName = 'AMC';
    }
    if ($type == '4C') {
        $tableName = '4C';
    }
    if ($type == 'RENTAL') {
        $tableName = 'RENTAL';
    }
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tableName . ' WHERE ' . implode('AND', $query_array);
    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: This code still generate broken queries. You don't add quotes

Answer (score -1):

Just change your code in that way

```
foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != ''){ 
        $query_array[] = $key." = '".$value . "'";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there is a `"` character in `$value`? This code is vulnerable to [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: @wormi4ok Moficul ask about how put quotes, but not how to protect from sql injections